# Получение параметров при использовании ssl

Tags: golang

Всем привет.
Планирую начать использовать ssl/tls сертификаты и встал вопрос. У меня в коде есть фрагменты передачи данных из форм такого типа

```
http://localhost:8080/?param1=value
```

Сейчас, без использования шифрования транспорта, я могу получить значение param1 так

```
r.FormValue("param1")
```

Вопрос:
если я начну шифровать транспорт, сами данные останутся незашифрованны ведь? Или мне придется изменить способ получения параметров из запроса и сперва эти параметры расшифровать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не важно шифруете ли вы транспорт или нет, в хендлер придут  данные в расшифровоном виде. Вот простой пример

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("param1=%s", r.FormValue("param1"))))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.NewServeMux()
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Команда генерация сертификатов

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 3650
```